# Calculating of consecutive occurrences in a slice list

Tags: python

I have a list of 81 items like below

```
myList = [A, A, A, A, A, B, A, A, C, A, B, A, A, B, B, A, B, C, A, C, A, A, C, B, A, C, C, B, A, A, B, A, B, B, A, C, B, B, A, B, B, B, B, B, C, B, C, A, B, C, B, B, C, C, C, A, A, C, A, B, C, A, C, C, B, A, C, B, B, C, B, C, C, C, A, C, C, B, C, C, C]
```

I have already slice myList to 3 elements per list

```
 for i in range(0,len(myList ),3):
     miniList= myList [i:i + 3]
```

so the miniList will now be

```
[A,A,A] consecutive Occurrence
[A,A,B]
[A,A,C] 
.
.
.
[C,C,C] consecutive Occurrence
```

I then wrote a function called

```
def countOccurrence(miniList):
    count = 1 
    Num_Sequence = 0 
    for i in range(len(miniList)-1):
        if miniList[i] == miniList[i+1]:
            count +=1
            if(count == 3):
                Num_Sequence += 1
                print(miniList) #debugging purposes
                print(Num_Sequence) #debugging purposes

    return Num_Sequence
```

The Num_Sequence is suppose to return 3 instead of 1. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: can you tell us what the "consecutive occurrences" is exactly?

Comment: You mean should it return 3 when all the characters in array are same?

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborate. so if the miniList is have all same character for example [A,A,A] then it returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not comparing 0th and 2nd element i.e. you do only the comparison with the next element to current checked - meaning there will never be a third match.

Instead I would suggest you try this - it skips the loop entirely:

```
def countOccurrence(miniList):
    count = 1
    Num_Sequence = 0

    if miniList.count(miniList[0]) == 3:
        Num_Sequence = 3
        return Num_Sequence

    return Num_Sequence
```

What this program does is checks if there are 3 occurrences of the first element in `miniList`. Since the `miniList` size is three, the only way occurrence will be 3 is if all elements are equal, so it doesn't matter which is used for comparison.

I ran this as follows:

```
for i in range(0,len(myList ),3):
    miniList= myList [i:i + 3]
    print countOccurrence(miniList)
```

And got a 3 at the end as expected.

This is the solution for the case that you actually want `miniList` to be a list of 3 element sublists:

```
miniList = [];
for i in range(0,len(myList ),3):
    miniList.append(myList [i:i + 3])
```

This appends each sublist to `miniList`. The `countOccurence` is still valid. You can apply the same `append` logics to get counts for every element of `miniList`:

```
out = [];
for elem in miniList:
    out.append(countOccurrence(elem))
```

Comment: Its still the same, if you add a print statement on countOccurrence. print("miniList"), it prints just [C,C,C]. Not [A,A,A],[B,B,B],[C,C,C]

Comment: This may be it?

Answer (score 2):

`zip(*[iter(myList)]*3)` - this will split the list into chunks of 3

```
[ i for i in zip(*[iter(myList)]*3) if len(set(i)) == 1 ]
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B', 'B'), ('C', 'C', 'C')]
```

To get the length

```
len([ i for i in zip(*[iter(myList)]*3) if len(set(i)) == 1 ])
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `Num_Sequence` is a local variable inside the function of `countOccurrence(miniList)`. So each time your function is called, the variable is created again and never it will reach 3. 
Change your code like this.

```
Num_Sequence = 0   # Good habit is to start your variable with lowercase, not uppercase

def countOccurrence(miniList):
    global Num_Sequence   # Indicating that you are going to change the global variable.
    # Rest of your code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues in your code that make it complex and give a wrong result.

First of all, as said by others, you don't compare the third character with the others.

Second, you use too many iterations and counting variables.

Third, `miniList= myList [i:i + 3]` just creates a [C, C, C,] list.

A more simple and clear implementation could look like this:

```
A = 'A'
B = 'B'
C = 'C'

miniList = []

myList = [A, A, A, A, A, B, A, A, C, A, B, A, A, B, B, A, B, C, A, C, A, A, C, B, A, C, C, B, A, A, B, A, B, B, A, C,
          B, B, A, B, B, B, B, B, C, B, C, A, B, C, B, B, C, C, C, A, A, C, A, B, C, A, C, C, B, A, C, B, B, C, B, C,
          C, C, A, C, C, B, C, C, C]

for i in range(0,len(myList),3):
    miniList.append(myList[i:i + 3])

print(miniList)

def countOccurrence(miniList):
    Num_Sequence = 0
    for item in miniList:
        print(item)
        if (item[0] == item[1] and item[0] == item[2]):
            Num_Sequence += 1
            print(item, '\n') #debugging purposes
            print(Num_Sequence, '\n') #debugging purposes

    return Num_Sequence

result = countOccurrence(miniList)
print(result)
```

I just assigned the A, B, C, variables to characters so i can work on it. Also i added some checking prints.